# Как прочитать текущие цвета QPalette() элемента QApplication в pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence, QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

app = QApplication([])

palette = QPalette()
palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
```

Как мне прочитать значение цвета Window которое сейчас установлено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно так же как и вы в своем примере его устанавливаете

```
color = palette.color(QPalette.Window)
```

Более подробно тут https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#color-1

Цвета в Qt представлены классом QColor, экземпляр которого и возвращается. Если надо получить RGB или другие параметры, работайте уже с QColor

```
color = palette.color(QPalette.Window)
name = color.name()
rgb = f'RED={color.red()} GREEN={color.green()} BLUE={color.blue()}'
print(f'by name: {name}\n as RGB: {rgb}\n')
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html

Comment: Sergey Tatarincev, Тогда почему вывод на экран такой: <PyQt5.QtGui.QColor object at 0x0000017693611890>

Comment: в ответе дополнил что вы получаете

Comment: Sergey Tatarincev, Спасибо, все ок, прошу дополнить ответ, в упрощенном виде: print(palette.color(QPalette.Window).name())